# How to install R version 3

Tags: r, version

After having some problems to install new version of R from command line on Ubuntu (straightforward way just updated it to version **2.15.x**)

I want to share the way to do this.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is an old post and I wrote it when it was impossible to install R with simple (it was installing old `2.15` version):

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

Right now you do not need to do all written below and can simply use the abovementioned command. At the time of updating it will give you `3.1` version.

**Here is previous post**

Uninstall old R

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
```

Open sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add deb to it

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

precise is your ubuntu name (may be different)

Add key to sign CRAN packages

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Add specific PPA to the system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rdev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

installing

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

From R to check version

```
version
```

should give you

```
version.string R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
```

Hope people will find this helpful

Comment: Check https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ for updated instructions.

Comment: This works. But don't forget to replace "precise" with your Ubuntu name https://cran.rstudio.com/ .